# IN which file error gets stored if installation of anything fails

Tags: linux, logging

I was installing some software on my linux system and then i get long list of errors.
Now i can go up and see when did it starts so i want to know the log file where the full error gets stored so that i can look when it started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look in `/var/log`. Depending on the severity of the error the error message may appear in different log files.